# is there a way of adding package/module to livetex (Latex) manually

Tags: module, package, latex

**Note: I am using Linux ubuntu**
And I am using latex for compiling a file to get pdf. The file contains

> a pseudocode of an algorithm

but it requires a package to use those **big O notations** like symbols. Since I have downloaded that package separately so it needs to be added manually
**How can I add it to livetex so it should load the package?**

Any help is appreciated. If you still don't get any part of my question. **I am ready to explain immediatel**y. Thank you

Comment: Are you using vanilla texlive or the one from the ubuntu package manager? And please also tell which package is missing

Comment: As quick hack: download the .sty file and place it in the same folder than your .tex file. The you should be able to use it with `\usepackage{clrscode3e}`

Comment: "I am ready to explain immediately." -> maybe answering the questions from comment posted nearly 2 years ago would be a good starting point?